# ASP.NET HttpModule - guaranteed execution of pre- and post- handler code?

Tags: c#, asp.net, httpmodule

Basically, I'm trying to write the following (pseudocode) in an ASP.NET HttpModule:

```
*pre-code*
try { handler.ProcessRequest(...) }
catch (Exception) { *error-code* }
finally { *post-code* }
```

I've found that I can hook into HttpModule.PreExecuteHandler for "pre-code" and .Error for "error-code".  But PostExecuteHandler doesn't seem to be running reliably.

BeginRequest and EndRequest run reliably but are too early for the code I need to write, which requires inspection of the handler that was chosen to execute.  The handler isn't chosen until after BeginRequest.

Is there a best practice for writing this kind of wrapper?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to do what you want (in a HttpModule, at least), other than to not call Response.End. [This article](http://www.west-wind.com/Weblog/posts/494.aspx) explains it pretty well and offers an alternative to Response.End in case it is a side-effect of your having called Server.Transfer.

Comment: Thanks - that's exactly what I was looking for, not for Server.Transfer but for Request.End().  PostRequestHandlerExecute definitely doesn't execute, but I think that EndRequest does get called even in this case?  Oh well, I'll go test...

Answer (score -2):

Add this to your Global.asax file:

```
protected void Application_PreRequestHandlerExecute(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //
}

protected void Application_PostRequestHandlerExecute(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //
}
```

That should work 100%.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the answer - but I'm looking to do this without a Global.ASAX file, in an HttpModule.  Also, I believe (but haven't yet tested in an ASAX) that if someone does a Response.End inside the handler, the PostRequestHandlerExecute will never run.  Only the End event will.. (?)